# Is there a specific instance of a Fourier series for which the interchange of the limit and integral is helpful?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to understand better why the Lebesgue integral is an improvement over the Riemann integral in the context of Fourier series.  I have seen this post:

[Riemann/Lebesgue Integral and Fourier Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453549/riemann-lebesgue-integral-and-fourier-series)

And I've read certain other historical writing that reflects the idea that Lebesgue may have originally been motivated to construct his theory of integration in order to get around certain difficulties with Fourier series.

That all makes sense, but I was wondering if there is a specific Fourier series that one could point to, and say "If you try to find its coefficients with the usual integration techniques, it will be hard.  But if you can interchange the limit and the integral, it becomes easy."

Most of the answers that I've found for why the Lebesgue integral is helpful here, is the completeness of $L^p$ space which is used in the proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.  That's a very good motivation, but I was wondering if there were a simpler and more concrete application which could be understood by a person just starting a course in Real Analysis.

Comment: Have you ever Fourier transformed a random signal?  Such integrals are (almost surely) not Riemann integrable.  (One difficulty is that random signals frequently have infinite energy, so don't live in $L^2$.  Another is that the upper and lower Riemann sums have no hope of agreeing.)